# Why is a function defined in the __init__.py not visible in a python file in that package?

Tags: python

In the `__init__.py`:

```
def tp(msg,o=None):
  import datetime
  omsg = ": %s" %repr(o) if o is not None else ""
  dtf = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
  print(f"[{dtf}] {msg}{omsg}")
```

In a `.py` file  in the same directory (/package ?) :

[image]

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/git/bluej/python/pointr/bluej/fusion/json_generators.py", line 243, in <module>
    tp('Running human-in-loop tests ..')
NameError: name 'tp' is not defined
```

What is the point of having `__init__.py` if the contents are not even visible to the files in the same package?

RE: the linked question and answers. It/they do not actually address my question here.

**Update**  I learnt how to run the script as a `module` within `pycharm` and that mostly  took care of the issue.  The `tp()` runs now: but it is still required to do

```
  from . import tp
```

[image]

Comment: `__init__.py` is supposed to be a package's initialization code. It's not intended to be pseudo-globals.

Comment: Python won't implicitly follow the package hierarchy upward, looking for a `tp`. This is similar to how instance attributes need to be accessed explicitly as attributes, even inside an object's own methods. If you want to access something in a different namespace (and it is a different namespace), you can do that explicitly.

Comment: What does "initialization code" mean if it does not include defining shared methods.

Comment: I looked at that linked question and it does not address my question here.  .

Comment: There isn't really a better way to answer "why doesn't it work that way?". It can only work one way - in this case, the way described in the link.

Comment: except that it is an _incorrect_ answer.  The function _does_ show up - when the package is marked as a _module_ .  That was the key

Comment: That makes no sense. What made the function available was the explicit `from . import tp`.

Comment: There is no such thing as marking a package as a module.

Comment: It seems neither of you understood  the requirements within `Pycharm` as indicated in the dialog  above.  It was surprising to me as well.

Comment: Do you think the "Module name:" box is marking a package as a module? It's not. It's specifying a module you want to run. A package is a kind of module; there is no marking involved.

Comment: On closer inspection, I suppose you were running the code by file path before. Running a package submodule by file path does nasty things to the import system, breaking the package and preventing things like `from . import tp` from working. You need to specify it by module name. (On the command line, this would be by running `python -m package.submodule` from somewhere `package` is importable.)

Comment: Unfortunately, running package submodules by file path is a very natural thing for new Python programmers to try. Python's import system is confusingly designed and full of awkward pitfalls like that.

Comment: There are more red flags here, like the `pointr.bluej` in the package hierarchy, that suggest there may be further problems, and I suspect it may not make sense to use a package here at all, but it's hard to tell from just this.

Comment: We have a few projects and in each project a few packages each with a number of files/modules: and then we work with partners whose code needs to be orthogonal to ours.  It's  maybe fifty-ish python files - plus the assorted resources.   Collapsing one level is maybe possible but probably not more than that.